# Not able to make call / join meeting in Microsoft Teams | Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, microsoft

I had installed MS Teams using .deb file which is downloaded from the MS site, and also I installed using snap as well.

I am facing the same issue in both installation options while making the call with a team or joining the meeting calls.

I hope this is some dependencies issues. please help to figure out this.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop: KDE

[Error Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fscsi.png)

Comment: IF you start teams in the terminal, are any error messages logged when you fail to connect?

Comment: opening the teams, error is here,
igPath = /home/jawad846/snap/teams-for-linux/105/.config/teams-for-linux
Failed to get the config file, using default values
configFile = {}
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Failed: cannot use setting "default-url-scheme-handler": not allowed
processArgs [ '/snap/teams-for-linux/105/teams-for-linux' ]
did-finish-load
did-finish-load